# regex to capture a character followed by itself or other specific characters in a single group

Tags: regex

I am trying to handle a code where comments can be designated with `!`, `!!`, or `!>`.

I want to match all of these possibility in a single group but am having difficulty as whatever I try so far might match the `!` in `!!` or `!>` etc. as a separate entity.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/u0vMY6/2

If anyone can help with this that would be great and help me to make progress.

More specifically I want to do this with the overall objective of matching when there are 0 or 2+ spaces after the comment deliniator followed by a word.

I have an summary of what I am trying to achieve here: https://regex101.com/r/u0vMY6/4

If needed I could perhaps break it down into multiple checks.

I'm not very experienced with regex but have read various cheatsheets and stackoverflow questions without finding a solution yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where does the `!$` come in? What is the rule regarding this? `! $` cannot match since there is a space and a non-whitespace right after `!`.

Comment: The rule regarding this is that it is acceptable to have `!$` followed by word(s), but in this instance with exactly 0 spaces between `!$` and the word. I am willing to try and place this in a different ruleset, however, as it might be too complicated to do all of this in one.

Comment: The first example link you posted seems to be working as you want it to. What's the issue there?

Comment: It's matching in both the should and should not. I think the later context (second link) is important to the functionality, apologies.

Comment: Try `![!>#]?(?:(?=[^\s!>#$]|\s{2}|\s\$)|\$(?!\S))`

Comment: Wow, thanks! Is it possible to capture the words after the comment in a group as well?

Comment: Here's what I came up with: https://regex101.com/r/afEWb0/1 As you mentioned, it would probably be better to match the `$` lines in a separate step, but it was still a fun challenge.

Comment: Sure - `![!>#]?(?:(?=[^\s!>#$]|\s{2}|\s\$)|\$(?!\S))\s*(.*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's great, thanks, and I will accept your answer. The delay is that I'm trying to implement this in Python and it's having issues recognising the `{2}`. Something to do with nesting? I realise it's beyond the original scope, but do you have any insight?

Comment: Duh, rather than trying to be clever I just replaced it by `\s\s`.
Thank you!

Comment: @FluidFox There should be no problem with `{2}`, unless you are using variables in an f-string. Then just double the curly braces, `f"{{2}}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you can use is

```
(![!>#]?(?:(?=[^\s!>#$]|\s{2}|\s\$)|\$(?!\S)))\s*(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HuN4W9/2).

*Details*:

- `![!>#]?` - a `!` char followed by an optional `!`, `>`, `#`
- `(?:(?=[^\s!>#$]|\s{2}|\s\$)|\$(?!\S))` - either of the two:

  - `(?=[^\s!>#$]|\s{2}|\s\$)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location if it is immediately followed with

    - `[^\s!>#$]` - any char other than whitespace, `!`, `>`, `#`, `$`
    - `|` - or
    - `\s{2}` - two whitespaces
    - `|` - or
    - `\s\$` - whitespace and then a `$` char
  - `|` - or
  - `\$(?!\S)` - a `$` char followed with a whitespace boundary
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks for not only providing a solution, but also explaining so that I can get better at understanding regex.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your examples seem sort of arbitrary I have written two functioning versions of the requested regex:

**1.** `(!>|!{1,2})(?: {2,})?\w+|\d+` - this one matches all your "need to match" strings and doesn't match any other strings in the given test.
**2.** `(?:(!>|!{1,2})(?: {2,})?\w+|\d+)|(?:(?:(!) \$)|(?:!\$ \w+|\d+))` - this one only matches your "need to match" and "ideally should match" strings, but because I do not really understand what pattern you want to match exactly I can not guarantee that it will pass further testing. But it gives with your examples the desired results!